# How to add support for a new language in FlashDevelop?

Tags: .net, plugins, flashdevelop

I am interested in making a plugin for [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org) to add support for another language. I am not too sure where I should start. So any starting points, hint, tips, or advice would go down well.

There is a [Plugin Development article on the FlashDevelop Wiki](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Plugin_Development#Syntax_highlighting_and_auto-completion), but the section about adding support for new languages is just a "TODO". So this is less than helpful.

I guess there are a number of parts to "supporting" a language in FlashDevelop. Here is my list, but feel free to tell me if I've missed something:

- **Code Completion**
- **Syntax Highlighting**
- Should appear in the **"New Project" menu** as a Template
- Should add file type/template to the **"Add->New" menu**
- Add the new **project filetype** (e.g. .as3proj, .as3proj, .hxproj).

So how do I do all of these things? Where do I even start? Are there any good resources, documentation, or basic examples to follow? Can all of this (including the project templates) be done inside one plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom language in FlashDevelop is easy once you get the hang of it. An example of creating a language for FlashDevelop would to look at the support for AS3 or even Haxe which can be found here [here](https://code.google.com/p/flashdevelop/source/browse/trunk/FD4#FD4%2FExternal%2FPlugins), all the support for languages end with context.

FlashDevelop deals with syntax highlighting for you while code completion is done by creating XML files.

Adding a template for your language is basically creating a zip file with a different extension. You can just copy the templates FlashDevelop comes with which are located in your installation folder and in the templates folder.